# ajax abort is not aborting on the server, only for the client

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Apparently I use

```
var x=ajax.....

if(x){x.abort();}
```

but this does not cause an abortion inside my php file, which by the way although the option is by default it is set to ignore_user_abort(false)

meaning that if connection were to be lost then the script would not continue execution.

The problem is it appears it keeps on executing code although ajax on js client side aborted.

How to accomplish via js the successful abortion of both, client side and server side php stopping.

Comment: `ignore_user_abort()` does not immediately terminate on disconnect, it takes time for the webserver to realize that a disconnect happened, and then to pass it on to PHP. Sending output helps to get it sooner, outputting a lot of empty spaces for instance in json or html context (=won't effect rendering/functionality) makes the detect sooner.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the way AJAX works in most cases.  Once the request is made to the server, the server starts to fulfill it. Even if PHP was set to stop script execution if the client connection was dropped, in a web server configuration, it does not make such a check until output is actually attempted to be sent to the client.  So if you are executing a typical AJAX type of script where you simply have a single output event, a client side abort is not going to have any effect on the server side.

Comment: allright, any way with a second function to be called right after js abort that sends input to be fetched with php to have the php process to stop, sessions? and abort if abort_sessionid is set for example? why doesn't ajax stop equal to a browser window close which in theory would make the php script stop automatically? thank you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php says that calling that function will cause the script to abort if the client disconnects (aborts) So it will have an effect, you can't guarantee that the PHP script actually aborted, but it will try to abort.

Comment: @JuanMendes Reed the `Notes` section on that page.  While what you say is true, the fact that PHP does not try to actually detect the abort until it attempts to output to client makes the client side abort useless in most AJAX type of scenarios where perhaps the server-side script is accessing a database and then is only returning a small content fragment. Doing the abort will still make the script execute up to the point where the out is actually about to be sent.

Comment: I see, a bunch of the comments on http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php explain that a workaround for this is for you to immediately flush some whitespace back to the client. That should cause the abort to happen sooner, but you still can't completely rely on it. You need something else to track that a job finished if you must track it.

Comment: @JuanMendes Yes but chances are the client side user hasn't hit abort at that time, because that response would be near instantaneous (unless there was large delay in actually reaching the server and the server beginning top process the request). Most likely the user would want to abort in the middle of some lengthy database operation or something like that, in which case you would again have to wait until the next output is sent to detect the connection drop. I guess the bottom line is that you really shouldn't rely on a client side abort to do much of anything on the server.

Comment: That's the main point of my answer, you can't rely on aborts really aborting, you'd need a system to check if a job finished or not

Comment: @JuanMendes Yes I don't disagree with your answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to confirm that something was aborted you have to send another request to ask if your job finished or not. That means that after you call `xhr.abort()` you have to send a request to something like `/abort/jobId` to find out whether it was able to abort before finishing processing.

There's no magic way to guarantee that the PHP script will stop immediately after the `abort()` call.