# Stopping requests server-side

Tags: php, ajax, apache, unix

I've got a name lookup box that operates by your typical ajax requests.  Here's the general flow of the Javascript that fires every time a letter is pressed:

- If ajax request already open, then abort it.
- If timeout already created, destroy it.
- Set new timeout to run the following in half a second:
- Send string to 'nameLookup.php' via ajax
- Wait for response
- Display results

The issue is that nameLookup.php is very resource heavy.  In some cases up to 10,000 names are being pulled from an SQL database, decrypted, and compared against the string.  Under normal circumstances requests can take anywhere from 5 to 60 seconds to return.

I completely understand that when you abort a request on the client side the server is still working on things and sends back the result.  That it's just the client side that knows to ignore the response.  But the server is getting so hung up on working on all of these requests.

So if you do:

- Request 1
- Abort Request 1
- Request 2
- Abort Request 2
- Request 3
- Wait for response from Request 3

The server is either not even working on Request 3 until it's finished with 1 and 2... or it's just so hung up on working on Request 1 and 2 that Request 3 is taking an extra long amount of time.

I need to know how to tell the server to stop working on Request 1 and 2 so I can free up resources for it to work on Request 3.

I'm using Javascript & jQuery on the client side.  PHP/Apache and SQL on the server side.

Comment: have you tried caching the results returned? Personally i'd recommend installing and using memcached. add a class and you can expire the results after 1 month or 1 week depending on your needs

Comment: also, have a look at the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886501/ajax-abort-is-not-aborting-on-the-server-only-for-the-client

Comment: I agree with other comments that you simply have an architecture problem. What is the cardinality of the data being queried (i.e. would caching make sense).  What is size of data? Could it fit into trie structure or similar search tree to make the lookups more efficient?

Comment: Possible reasons why caching results won't work: 1) The data is encrypted for a reason.  I don't want unencrypted data being cached anywhere else.  2) New names are constantly being added to the system.

Comment: @LiamSorsby I've seen a bunch of posts like this which only validate my understanding of what's happening with abort();  I've seen some posts that only mention that the process on Apache is kinda difficult... but not give any clues on how to go about it.

Comment: @rgbflawed the caching is coming from the MySQL database so if your data is encrypted on the database side then you can store the values that are cached as encrypted data. It would still increase the speed. Also please note that the cached data would remain on your server and on your server only using memcached. Also would you not be able to stop the script executing by running. An alternative is to get the script to return a pid from the server and then on executing the abort initialise a kill pid. However i'm not entirely sure on if this would be a safe way to do it.

Comment: @LiamSorsby your mention of killing pids lead me to some research which lead me to a really great solution! (which I've added below)  Thanks for lighting the spark, man!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've come up with an awesome solution that I've tested and it's working beautifully.  It's just a few lines of PHP code to put in whatever files are being resource intensive.

This solution utilizes the [Process Identifier (PID)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/kill-process-in-linux-or-terminate-a-process-in-unix-or-linux-systems/) from the server.  We can use two PHP function: posix_getpid() to get the current PID and posix_kill() to kill another PID.  This also assumes that you already have called session_start() somewhere else.

Here's the code:

```
//if any existing PIDs to kill, go through each
if ($_SESSION['pid']) foreach ($_SESSION['pid'] as $i => $pid) {

    //if posix_kill returns true, unset this PID from the session so we don't waste time killing it again
    if(posix_kill($pid,0)) unset($_SESSION['pid'][$i]);

}

//now that all others are killed, we can store the current PID in the session
$_SESSION['pid'][]=posix_getpid();

//close the session now, otherwise the PID we just added won't actually be saved to the session until the process ends.
session_write_close();
```

Couple things to note:

[posix_kill](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-kill.php) has two values.  The first is the pid, and the second is supposed to be one of the signal constants from [this list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.constants.php).  Nothing there made any sense to me, other people seemed to have success just using 0, and when I use 0 it returns true.  So whatever works!

calling [session_write_close()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) before the resource intensive things start happening is crucial.  Otherwise the new PID that has been saved to the session won't ACTUALLY be saved to the session until all of the page's processing is done.  Which means the next process won't know to cancel the one that's still going on and taking forever.

Comment: This seems like a really bad solution... You shouldn't have to mess with the processes on the server, there must be a better solution.

Comment: @FabienWarniez Well, I've got this thing going and already things that used to take a minute to complete are taking 3 seconds.  What's the problem with killing a process like this?  Will I crash the server?  Will I open a security vulnerability?

Comment: Different things: 1. killing processes can leave the DB or the filesystem in a random state, based on what the script was doing when you killed it. 2. maintainability 3. based on where you host the code, you might not always have permissions to do that. 4. There is a reason for 3., it's a security breach, you are giving your code too much power/permissions, it'd better be very robust and bullet-proof.

Comment: See my answer for an alternative solution that doesn't involve killing processes.

Comment: Last, notice how it's called "killing" processes, not "pausing" or "gently stopping" or "cancelling"? Again, there is a reason.

Comment: @FabienWarniez 1) I'm just doing one SELECT sql pull, not writing anything.  I doubt SQL, or Apache, is so fragile that it's going to have a problem with this. 2) I'm maintaining just fine, thankyou.  3) Where it's hosted now it works.  I have no plans to change hosting 4) If someone has found a way to take advantage of the SESSION variables on my server, or has figured out a way to use this to kill their own processes, I'm in way more world of hurt than what they can do by just these few lines of code.

Comment: Is the SQL pull taking a long time? Or the PHP that does some processing on it? You are missing all the points by the way.

Comment: @FabienWarniez the one SQL pull happens very quickly and is done right off the bat.  It's the PHP processing/decrypting that takes forever.

Comment: Ok. Any chance you can improve this processing? I would into that.

Comment: @FabienWarniez yes I've of course looked into this.  Decrypting 10,000 names just takes a long time no matter how you slice it.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to decrypt them all. Or maybe you can encrypt the name you are looking for and compare that to the encrypted names directly, for example.

Comment: I agree to all the points @FabienWarniez shows up. Nevertheless there is a line I use all the time to unlock the server request : session_write_close(); This writes the session file and unlock the other oricessus trying to open the session file (usually at process beginning). Unfortunally this does not answer the question, running processes that are cancelled by the user are still running and the server ressources are still used. (I also answer on your solution FabienWarniez, which doens not suit to me)

Comment: Nicolas, do consider the solution I posted. This code has been running beautifully on my server for over a year now with no issues. I think Fabien just didn't understand the limitations of encryption and how there are no shortcuts.

Comment: Awesome solution indeed, but just keep in mind, this solution may not work if you have multiple simultaneous requests coming in from within the same session. This is typical scenario with single-page JS based applications where multiple 'server calls' are made and results are fetched simultaneously instead of sequentially. You will inadvertently end up having some calls killing other calls, which may be completely undesirable effect.

Comment: Umesh reminded me of this post again.  Just thought I'd post yet again and say this code has been working great for me for years and I've experienced absolutely zero negative effects.  Maybe one day someone else will read this post and benefit from the same.  And maybe that person will upvote my answer!

Answer (score 1):

1. Store a boolean value in the DB in a table, or in the session.
2. Have your resource intensive script check periodically that value to see if it should continue or not. If the DB says to stop, then your script cancels itself (by calling `return;` in the current function for example).
3. When you want to cancel, instead of calling `abort();`, make an AJAX request to set that value to `false`.
4. Next time the resource checks that value it will see that it has to stop.

Potential limitations:
 1. Your script does not have a way of checking periodically the DB.
 2. Based on how often the script checks the DB, it might take a few seconds to effectively kill the script.

Comment: This is an interesting way of doing it too.  I'm concerned about having to make tons and tons of extra calls to the SQL to check if things should continue.  I'm also concerned about the "check periodically" part of this.  It will be very difficult to define what periodically means.  Of course in this resource intensive script there's a lot of looping going on, but the length of time that one loop takes will be totally different depending on the input that's been typed in and the results that get pulled out of the SQL.

Comment: That's why I suggested the session as well. It could be memcache, it could be any way of storing this boolean so that a simple AJAX call can read/write it.

Comment: Hi @FabienWarniez, I just come to this thread searching for a solution to my issue. I want to stop a request "cancelled" by the browser. This happens when the user switch to another webpage before the first request answer. When you hit F12 in chrome, you can see the request in red with Cancelled status. This can occur all the time for each request and I dont want to manage a database store and check for each request... (although few are long btw, maybe 20). Isn't there a better trick ? Can't the browser send a signal to the server for a cancelled request (It is the only to know it after all) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something missing from this question.  What are the triggers for doing the requests?  You might be trying to solve the wrong problem.

Let me elaborate on that.  If you lookup box is actually doing autocompletion of some kind and is doing a new search everytime the user presses a key, then you are going to have the issue you describe.

The solution in that case is not killing all the process.  The solution lies in not starting them.  So, you might make some decisions like not trying to search if there is only one character to search with - lets say we go for three.  We then might say we want to wait until we can be reasonable sure the user has finished typing before sending off the request.  Lets say we wait 1 second.

Now, someone looking for all the Paul's in you list of names will send off one search when they type 'pau' and pause for 1 second, instead of three searches for 'p' then 'pa' then 'pau'... so no need to kill anything.